# How to add rows to a Grid in front end?

Tags: front-end, grid-layouts

I created a grid `g1` with `Grid[]` and then a separate grid `g2`.  `g1` and `g2` have same number of columns.  How to put the rows of `g2` at the end of `g1` purely using front-end?  I tried to highlight `g2`, Ctrl+C, and move my curser to various positions in `g1` and Ctrl+V.  But it always resulted in something not desirable such as the entire `g2` being copied into a cell of `g1`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So You want to create something like Grid@{gi1, gi2,...,hi1,hi2..} without evaluating anything? (gi1 is first row of g grid). Or do You want it to only look like grid with more rows?

Comment: something like that: `g1 = Grid[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, Frame -> All]`, `g2 = Grid[{{w, x}, {y, z}}, Frame -> All]`, and then `g3=Grid[g1[[1]]~Join~g2[[1]], Frame -> All]`?

Comment: @PinguinDirk  You're right.

Comment: Could you explain why you would want to do something like that using the FrontEnd? I honestly can't find a good use for it. If you'd have to recalculate either of those grids for whatever reason you'd have to manipulate them again in the FrontEnd. Very cumbersome.

Answer (score 6):

Say you have two `Grid`:

[image]

First place the cursor at the end of the last row:

[image]

Then use menu command *Add Row* (please note the short-cut) to add as many rows as `g2` has:

[image]

[image]

Then copy `g2` by dragging from the items (not by select the whole grid or cell!):

[image]

Then select all empty rows you just created in `g1` and paste:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you think of any way to do this without creating as many rows as needed manually?  I cannot think of a way myself, though I'm hoping one exists.  +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I can't think of one for now, so I would not suggest doing this for large grid.. I'll try it after lunch. Maybe something related to `ArrayFlatten`..

Comment: @Silvia's solution is acceptable for my problem at hand. But in general, having to click once for each new row needed seems rather bad.

Comment: @red3y3 To make it feeling (slightly) better, you can *press* the short-cut instead of *click* the menu. But still, this is very annoy.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I give up.. I think it's too complicated FE programming for a not-so-useful function..

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach: define a function which can combine two grids preserving the union of their options.

```
rows = Partition[Range[5 3], 3];
g1 = Grid[rows[[;; 3]], Frame -> All]
```

[image: g1.png]

```
g2 = Grid[rows[[4 ;;]], Frame -> All]
```

[image: g2.png]

```
JoinGrids[Grid[data1 : {__}, opts1 : ___], 
          Grid[data2 : {__}, opts2 : ___]] := 
  Grid[Join[data1, data2], Sequence @@ Union[{opts1, opts2}]]

JoinGrids[g1, g2]
```

[image: join12.png]

```
JoinGrids[g2, g1]
```

[image: join21.png]

```
g3 = Grid[rows[[4 ;;, ;; 2]], ItemStyle -> Red]
```

[image: g3.png]

```
JoinGrids[g2, g3]
```

[image: join23.png]

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first argument (not including options to Grid) is a 'matrix' (that is a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html?q=List&lang=en) of Lists in Mathematica).

Given the following example Grids:

```
Grid[
    {{a11, a12, a13},
    {a21, a22, a23},
    {a31, a32, a33}}
] 

Grid[
    {{b11, b12, b13},
    {b21, b22, b23},
    {b31, b32, b33}}
]
```

(Note that I have spread the syntax for each Grid over several lines using a keyboard return, but each Grid expression should be contained within a single notebook cell; see the brackets off to the right in the Front End.)

You should place a comma after the last 'row' of your first 'matrix', like so:

```
Grid[
    {{a11, a12, a13},
    {a21, a22, a23},
    {a31, a32, a33} , }
]
```

Then you copy the rows from your second Grid, being careful not to copy the outer curly braces, like so:

[image]

You then paste that copied set of lists ('rows' if you prefer) after the comma in your first Grid:

```
Grid[
    {{a11, a12, a13},
    {a21, a22, a23},
    {a31, a32, a33},
    {b11, b12, b13},
    {b21, b22, b23},
    {b31, b32, b33}}
]
```

With a shift-enter to evaluate the cell, you should have a nice Grid,

[image]

which you can then decorate with options to [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html?q=Grid&lang=en).

Comment: That's not what i meant. I want to operate on the resultant grids, not the defining code.